# Is there a git command that can get list of version of the project/file on the remote git repository server

Tags: git

suppose i have a file with version 4 and the same file on the remote repository server is version 8. I would like to get the list of versions for the project/file.

Then i would like to merge my file with may be version 6.

how would i got about doing this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note that in git, each version (commit) describes the complete state of your repository, rather than versioning on a per-file basis.*

You can do something like what you want with the following commands:

```
git fetch origin
```

This updates all your "remote-tracking branches" from the remote repository referred to as `origin`.  You can think of this as like updating the state of your local cache of all the branches from origin.

Then the following command will then list all the commits that introduced changes to the the file `docs/foo.txt` that you don't have in your current branch locally:

```
git log -p ..origin/master -- docs/foo.txt
```

The `-p` option says to also include a full diff between versions in the output.  You can leave that out for more concise output that just shows you the commit messages.

Comment: I am running this on windows the i run the last command i do not any any message not even an error. git log -p ..origin/master -- d:\testrep2\testrep

Comment: @kumar: If you leave out the `-- docs/foo.txt` (or equivalent), do you get any commits listed?  If none are listed, then your local branch includes all the history of the remote one already.

Comment: Thanks it is working but is there a way to format the log result i just want to view the file modified, date of modification,comment,author. Currently it also shows even the line that have been modified.

Comment: @kumar: if you use `--stat` instead of `-p`, does that do what you want?